# Problem with XCode using a different GoogleService-Info based on selected schema

Tags: xcode, firebase

So far I've:

- Copied my original schema to create a dev and prod version
- Created the folders to store my separate GoogleService-Info
- Added the files into their respective folders
- During adding, I was prompted to choose which schema they should target, and chose their respective schemas

However, when I looked at their build phases, I noticed that both files were present in the Copy Bundle Resources section of their build phases. When I tried to change them, both changed. Is that supposed to happen, or where did I mess up?